# Scipy basin hopping minimization on function with free and fixed parameters

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a function which has as input a tuple of free parameters and a tuple of fixed parameters, and as output a scalar value. It is expensive to run, and I want to find the minimum of this function without having knwoledge of any gradients / Hessians. I decided to use the Basin hopping method for this, with as minimization function COBYLA, since in a test run with a cheap function, this used the least function calls and was able to use bounds.

However, I don't know how I can tell the Basin hopping method which parameters are free for optimization, and which are fixed.

```
def func(x_free, x_fixed):
    '''Do some expensive stuff here'''
    global FUNC_CALLS
    FUNC_CALLS += 1
    return scalar_value
```

In the documentation, I read that I can pass arguments to this func using the dictionary `minimizer_kwargs`. However, it does not explain which keywords I should use for that. Can anybody help me with a list of allowed keywords for `minimizer_kwargs`, and what they do?

Without the argument `x_fixed`, my code looks as follows:

```
from scipy.optimize._basinhopping import basinhopping
global FUNC_CALLS
FUNC_CALLS = 0
x0 = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "COBYLA"}
ret = basinhopping(func, x0, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs, niter=10)
print("Global minimum: x = [%.4f, %.4f, %.4f], f(x0) = %.4f" % (ret.x[0], ret.x[1], ret.x[2], ret.fun))
print("Number of function calls: {0}".format(FUNC_CALLS))
```

So in short: what should I do to insert `x_fixed` into the function?

Comment: Side note: You should not import from `_basinhopping`.  It is a private module.  Use `from scipy.optimize import basinhopping`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the docstring of [basinhopping](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html), add an `args` key to `minimizer_kwargs` with the value `(x_fixed,)`.

For example:

```
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "COBYLA", "args": (x_fixed,)}
```